# iOS app working fine on Simulator but crashing on iphone (Involves Array)

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, nsmutablearray, indexoutofboundsexception

[problem code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SNBl.png)

Printing the array count returns 15, which is fine. It doesn't seem like a problem on the other view controller because it doesn't print anything on viewDidLoad before setting anything. What confuses me more is that it works fine on the simulator but only crashes on iPhone. Please help!

Comment: Before use an array, u had better check it`s count to avoid crash.In your case，please post more info.

Comment: It is impossible for any of us to answer your question unless you edit it to include appropriate excerpts of actual source code. However, I can predict that the root cause of your problem is this: "you have a *timing* problem." A simulator might easily be several orders-of-magnitude slower than the real device.  In the simulator, real-world events (especially, "initial, on-startup" events) have plenty of time to happen before your code gets around to checking for them. On real hardware, it does not. Something's probably being tested before it has been initialized.

Comment: Your crash is during insertion into array, code you posted is only reading from it. You're crashing somewhere else

Comment: paste you complete code for that view controller